# Граббинг изображений товаров woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Проблема такая: на сайте WordPress + WooCommerce есть около 600 товаров, все они без изображений.
Функционал плагина: Плагин должен наполнять изображения товаров.
Знаю, что есть плагин с похожим функционалом на OpenCart. На WooCommerce ничего найти не смог.
Вручную это делать очень затратно (в плане времени).Возможно, что кто-нибудь знает плагины/решения. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: И в чем вопрос-то? И зачем инфа о каком-то непонятном плагине для опенкарта? Исправь вопрос.

Comment: Что плагин делать то должен?

Answer (score 0):

> WooCommerce есть около 600 товаров, все они без изображений.
>   Функционал плагина: Плагин должен наполнять изображения товаров.

Опять [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy) :)

Проще и правильнее это сделать с помощью нехитрой операции:
1. Временно залить куда-то картинки. (Можно на др. хостинг, можно в любой отдельный подкаталог текущего сайта, потом его удалить) и получить урлы на них. Важно - заливать не через ВП, а по ФТП напр.
2. Экспорт товаров.
3. Правка csv файла в Exel-подобном ПО, добавляя адреса нужных картинок соответствующим им товарам.
4. Импорт файла в WC
5. Убедиться что картинки залились в медиатеку, после чего удалить исходные картинки.

Сам экспорт-импорт файла можно делать как встроенным инструментом в WC, так и плагинами, коих [не мало](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/woocommerce+import+csv/).